# grocery-crud callback_before_insert not working

Tags: codeigniter, callback, grocery-crud

i'm trying to do a callback_before_insert, this is my script:

```
public function brandstof()
{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('invoer');
        $crud->set_subject('Brandstof');
        $crud->required_fields('datum', 'aant_km', 'ltr', 'prijs');
                    $crud->fields('datum', 'aant_dagen', 'aant_km', 'ltr', 'prijs');
                    $crud->order_by('datum', 'desc');
                    $crud->callback_before_insert(array($this,'calculate'));

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
}


    function calculate($post_array)
    {
        $post_array['tot'] = 100;
        $post_array['een_op'] = $post_array['aant_km'] / $post_array['ltr'];
        $post_array['ltr_per_100_km'] = $post_array['ltr'] / $post_array['aant_km'];
        return $post_array;
    }
```

the thing is that he only adds de regular fields, the one I type in myselfe.
but the calulated ones are not inserted

for testing purpose I added this:

```
        $post_array['tot'] = 100;
```

just make the field 'tot' 100
after I insert this phpmyadmin givesnull values when it comes to the calculated fields

I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.

So in grocery CRUD for security reasons you need to specify all the fields that you want to save at the fields method. Then you can simply have this type as [invisible](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/field_type#invisible-field). As you can see at the documentation for invisible field there is an example for the callback_before_insert . So in your case you will simply have:

```
public function brandstof()
{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('invoer');
        $crud->set_subject('Brandstof');
        $crud->required_fields('datum', 'aant_km', 'ltr', 'prijs');
        $crud->fields('datum', 'aant_dagen', 'aant_km', 'ltr', 
            'prijs','tot','een_op','ltr_per_100_km'); //Don't forget to add these fields

        $crud->field_type('tot','invisible');
        $crud->field_type('een_op','invisible');
        $crud->field_type('ltr_per_100_km','invisible');

        $crud->order_by('datum', 'desc');
        $crud->callback_before_insert(array($this,'calculate'));

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
}


function calculate($post_array)
{
    $post_array['tot'] = 100;
    $post_array['een_op'] = $post_array['aant_km'] / $post_array['ltr'];
    $post_array['ltr_per_100_km'] = $post_array['ltr'] / $post_array['aant_km'];
    return $post_array;
}
```

Comment: Hi John, I tested this, and I add all the fields and make some hidden, i copied your code and added the field ID as hidden, so all fields are in now, but still the same result. the calculated fields are not inserted. is there a way to use a vardum or print_r to check what's wrong? or can I manage to get a error message?

Comment: problem is solved now, 
john your answer was defenilty right.
I edited my script but when I displayed it, nothing happened.
That's because I was editing the wrong script, whell that makes perfect sense that it didn't work... well I go to my corner and shame my eyes out. thanks for you help John it works